# Global variable value in userform is not updated

Tags: excel, public

I need to define a global variable x and assign a value to the x according to the user's selection and then write the same value in two cells N2 and J2.    N2 happens within the userform and J2 outside of the userform. 
I first want to have a popup window for the user to select either the value 0.01 or 0.05. So I used userform to do this. But instead of running this userform directly, I wanted to call the userform in a vba module called macro2(), see below. In macro2(), I call the userform "user1" first, the pop up window will show allowing user to select either 0.01 or 0.05. If we select 0.01, then the global variable "x" will have the value 0.01. Then when we write the variable x in cell N2, N2 will have the value 0.01 (this is good).   But after the userform exits and continue the rest of macro2(), the cell J2 is 0 instead of 0.01 even though x should have the value 0.01.

This is pretty interesting because the second time when we select 0.05, N2 will have the value 0.05 but J2 will carry the old x value 0.01.  Could anyone help me with this?   I essentially need both N2 and J2 carry the same x value so I can call x in later code for many other things. Thanks!

My module/macro code look like this:

```
Global x As Double
Sub Macro2()
    Dim frm As user1
    user1.Show vbModeless
    Range("J2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = x
End Sub
```

The "user1" userform code is:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    Range("N2").Select
    x = 0.01
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = x
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    Range("N2").Select
    x = 0.05
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = x
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = x
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the `Range("J2")` update have to occur outside of the userform or can it be written at the same time as `Range("N2")`?

Answer (score 0):

`Sub Macro2()` writes the value of `x` to `Range("J2")` everytime it is called. This is why the old value is writing to `J2` the next time you run that sub.`

The `OptionButton_Click` events are only writing `x` to `Range("N2")` and then hide the form.

The only time you are writing anything to `Range("J2")` is when you run `Macro2` which explains your interesting results.

Using your code as is with some modification:

*In Module1:*

```
Global x As Double
Sub Macro2()
    Dim frm As User1
    User1.Show
End Sub
```

*In UserForm Module:*

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    x = 0.01
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("N2").Value = x
        .Range("J2").Value = x
    End With
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    x = 0.05
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("N2").Value = x
        .Range("J2").Value = x
    End With
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

This assigns the value of `x` the same as your code based on whichever `optionbutton` is clicked however it writes the value of `x` to both cells `J2` and `N2`.

Notice I've replaced the references to `ActiveCell` and explicitly declared which `Workbook/Worksheet` we are using.